# SQL Server - Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, inner-join

I need to identify all records that have MostRecent=-1, OilWell=-1, plus are duplicate records with the same Api, and join these to get the associated CompanyName.

With the query:

```
SELECT 
    BLMAPDCONTACT.CompanyName, APD.Api, APD.ID, APD.MostRecent, 
    APD.Project_Nu, APD.Unit_Lease, APD.Well_Nu, APD.OilWell
FROM 
    APD 
INNER JOIN 
    BLMAPDCONTACT ON APD.BLM_APD_Cont = BLMAPDCONTACT.OBJECTID
WHERE 
    (APD.Api IN (SELECT APD.Api 
                 FROM APD AS Tmp 
                 WHERE APD.MostRecent = -1 AND APD.OilWell = -1 
                 GROUP BY APD.Api 
                 HAVING Count(APD.Api) > 1))
ORDER BY 
    APD.Api DESC;
```

I get this error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

This error appeared after I added the `JOIN` clause; without it, it worked.

Example desired output will match on the following records from the APD table:

```
APD.Api | APD.MostRecent | APD.OilWell
--------------------------------------
123     | -1             | -1
123     | -1             | -1
```

And not:

```
APD.Api | APD.MostRecent | APD.OilWell
--------------------------------------
321     | 0              | -1
321     | -1             | -1
```

Comment: Hi. You are aliasing APD to tmp so you need to group an expression using a tmp column. Presumably the other inner select APD column references should use tmp instead too. But why alias? PS Please read & act on [mcve]. PS You ask about the error. But getting rows with subrows that are duplicates is a faq. So that's a way to see correct queries.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this:

```
SELECT BLMAPDCONTACT.CompanyName, APD.Api, APD.ID, APD.MostRecent, APD.Project_Nu, APD.Unit_Lease, APD.Well_Nu, APD.OilWell
FROM APD INNER JOIN BLMAPDCONTACT ON APD.BLM_APD_Cont = BLMAPDCONTACT.OBJECTID
WHERE (APD.Api IN 
    (SELECT tmp.Api 
    FROM APD As Tmp 
    WHERE tmp.MostRecent=-1 AND tmp.OilWell=-1 
    GROUP BY tmp.Api HAVING Count(tmp.Api)>1))
ORDER BY APD.Api DESC;
```

Comment: This runs; however, it gives me records with APIs whose MostRecent does not equal -1 and that are not duplicated. i.e. I need the output to show 2 (or more) results when the criteria described in the question are met. HTH.

Comment: Why?  What if there is only one matching result?

Answer (score 0):

The aliases and table names are confusing me a bit. If you run the following, do you still get the same error?

```
SELECT b.CompanyName
, a.Api
, a.ID
, a.MostRecent
, a.Project_Nu
, a.Unit_Lease
, a.Well_Nu
, a.OilWell
FROM APD a INNER JOIN BLMAPDCONTACT b
ON a.BLM_APD_Cont = b.OBJECTID
WHERE a.Api IN (
    SELECT tmp.Api 
    FROM APD As Tmp 
    WHERE tmp.MostRecent = -1 AND tmp.OilWell = -1 
    GROUP BY tmp.Api
    HAVING Count(tmp.Api) > 1
    )
ORDER BY a.Api DESC;
```

Also, just double check that I've translated tables to aliases correctly.

Comment: Same comment as above.

Comment: @KevinR.M. You're going to want to double-check the tables/aliases. The code you sent, the fields in the where and select clause appear to reference the outter query. I would alias all the tables and make sure they fields are referenced as makes sense for your use-case. If you still see issues after that, post the updated query and some sample data.

Comment: double checked - your tables & aliases are correct.
With this query I have (1 or more) results with incorrect criteria:

    APD.Api = 111; APD.MostRecent = 0; APD.OilWell = -1 - and that 111 is unique i.e. not a duplicate.